# Integrating avro into sbt workflow

Tags: java, scala, sbt, avro, sbt-assembly

I'm planning to use Avro schemas in my Scala-based project (built using `sbt`) and I'm trying to figure out the right way to include the Avro-based classes when building a far jar from my project (using `sbt assembly`).

Following is the list of steps I had in mind:

(a) Place the `avro` schema files in `src/main/avro`

(b) Generate `java/scala` classes from the schema files into `src/main/java` or `src/main/scala`

(c) Generate the fat jar.

**Questions**

(i) What would be the right way to get step (b) done? I noticed that the Apache Avro project provides a jar named [avro-tools-1.8.1.jar](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html) to generate java classes from the schema files. However, I'm not sure how this jar file can be used in an sbt-based workflow.

(ii) Another option I noticed is that there are third party sbt plugins (eg: [sbt-avrohugger](https://github.com/julianpeeters/sbt-avrohugger), [scavro](https://github.com/oedura/scavro), [sbt-avro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro), etc.). Is there an sbt plugin that's recommended? Since these are third-party plugins, I couldn't be sure which one's the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using:
[sbt-avro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro)

My configuration is as below in `build.sbt`:

```
seq(sbtavro.SbtAvro.avroSettings: _*)
(javaSource in avroConfig) := baseDirectory.value / "src/main/java/"
(stringType in avroConfig) := "String"
```

To generate the java file manually:

```
sbt avro:generate
```

To generate the fat jar:

```
sbt assembly
```

Comment: Thanks Binzi! Have you run into any issues while using sbt-avro? Or has it been stable?

Comment: Yeah, it is quite stable to use